# R: Adding days() interval to Datetime object in a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I have a datetime object called Download_date. I want to add an interval of 13 days to that object in a tibble, depending on the condition stated below.

```
Clean_Data[Clean_Data$Origin == "Site A" & Clean_Data$Ship_Mode == "AIR" &  Clean_Data$PO_Download_Date > Clean_Data$Receipt_Date, "Receipt_Date"] <- 
  Clean_Data[Clean_Data$Origin == "Site A" & Clean_Data$Ship_Mode == "AIR" &  Clean_Data$PO_Download_Date > Clean_Data$Receipt_Date, "PO_Download_Date"] + days(13)
```

When I ran this code, this is the error message that it gave me.

```
Error: Incompatible classes: <tbl_df> + <Period>
```

How can I resolve this issue? I did the same thing with just one datetime value, and worked fine. I am guessing that this is happening because I am working with data frame.

Answer (score 0):

We could subset with `$` or `[[` to extract the column from a `tibble`

```
i1 <- Clean_Data$Origin == "Site A" & Clean_Data$Ship_Mode == "AIR" & 
             Clean_Data$PO_Download_Date > Clean_Data$Receipt_Date
Clean_Data$Receipt_Date[i1] <- Clean_Data$PO_Download_Date[i1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if_else` with `mutate` to update `Receipt_Date` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Clean_Data <- Clean_Data %>%
  mutate(Receipt_Date = if_else(Origin == "Site A" &  
                                Ship_Mode == "AIR" & 
                                PO_Download_Date > Receipt_Date, 
                                PO_Download_Date + days(13), Receipt_Date)) 
Clean_Data
```